# My post was delete without warning and my account too

Tags: discussion, support

My post was deleted without warning and my account too.

This is the link to the answer that triggered it all:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/55539/15901

I think this is action was not according to the stackexchange spirit.

Answer (score 2):

Eduard - this post was flagged by the community for a couple of reasons: offensive and not an answer

Typically, if we see a new user arrive and make a post that is offensive or spam as their very first post, they don't get much sympathy.

I see looking at it that you have accounts on other Stack exchange sites, so you should be aware of the general requirements for a site.

Comment: By deleting the account you cannot see if the post wasn't offensive in anyway, my account was at least 6 months old if not an year, with some activity so I wasn't a new user. And I still think I didn't receive a good answer to this question.

I compared heartbeat transaction with CDOs transaction it may not be a good answer but definitely it is not offensive just because was flagged so.

Comment: This was your only post here. It gained a couple of flags. I reviewed it and agreed with the flags.

Comment: I agreed with the deleting of the post, but an explanation on why you found it offensive and why my account had been deleted would not have left me antagonized. Though thanks for the current answers which is better the none.